# Collapsing Toolbar inside ViewPager2 gives scrolling issues

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Good day. I have activity with viewpager 2 (horizontal direction) and fragment which used by this viewpager. This fragment contains collpasing toolbar and nested scroll view with scrolling content. When i triyng to scroll content of my fragment from bottom to top and when, i'am scrolling up, the finger moves a little to the side - the scrolling is interrupted and the horizontal scroll of the view pager is triggered. How i can disable horizontal-scroll of the view pager while i'am scrolling vertical nested scroll view?